# Querying a SQLite table to return rows with a specific ID

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the method that is suppose to take a `long ID` and return the row that matches the given id but something is wrong with my query and I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?  (the column containing the id values is called "ID")

```
public Cursor getAllData (long ID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long thisID = ID ;
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from WHERE ID = " + thisID + DataTableName,null);
    return result;        
}
```

Comment: What's "DataTableName"?

Comment: that is the name of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it as follows :

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataTableName + " WHERE ID = "+thisID,null);
```

And what @Danail Alexiev wanted to say to you I guess is this :

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataTableName + " WHERE ID = ?",new long[]{thisID});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "+": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from + jobsTable+ WHERE ID = 0

Comment: shouldn't there be plus signs before and after DataTableName?

Comment: Sorry I saw you updated it if it helped to you mark it as a correct and feel free to upvote it :)=

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is malformed. The right format is `select <columns> from <table> where <condition>`. You will get something like `select * from where <condition><table>`.

Another piece of advice - don't use string concatenation to build SQL queries. It's a very bad practice and opens up your app to SQL Injection attacks. Use the parameterised version of the query methods to prevent this.

Comment: so where do I specify the ID?

Comment: go with `select * from <your table name> where id = ?`. `?` is a placeholder for a parameter value, which you supply later. Check the Javadoc on the `rawQuery` method or simply use the `query` method.